# Can't get same Xvid quality and file size out of FFmpeg, as Mencoder

Tags: ffmpeg, mencoder, xvid

Before anyone asks "Why Xvid?", it works well when you have no video acceleration on a Allwinner SBC.

I'd like to use FFmpeg for all my Xvid encoding. But after doing my best to match setting between Mencoder and Xvid, the file size is anywhere from 10-15% larger with FFmpeg. However, the quality is pretty spot on.

Mencoder:

```
mencoder input.file -o output.file -vf scale=720:302 -sws 9 -nosound -ovc xvid -xvidencopts fixed_quant=3:me_quality=6:quant_type=h263:min_iquant=1:max_iquant=31:min_pquant=1:max_pquant=31:min_bquant=1:max_bquant=31:max_key_interval=250:quant_type=h263:max_bframes=2:bquant_ratio=150:bquant_offset=100:bf_threshold=0:vhq=4:bvhq=1:curve_compression_high=0:curve_compression_low=0:overflow_control_strength=10:max_overflow_improvement=10:max_overflow_degradation=10:trellis:noqpel:nogmc:nocartoon:nochroma_opt:nochroma_me:nointerlacing:par=ext:par_width=1:par_height=1:closed_gop:nopacked:threads=1 -of lavf
```

FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.file -an -vf scale=720x302 -sws_flags lanczos -c:v libxvid -flags +cgop -g 250 -trellis 2 -q:v 3 -bf 2 -qmin 1 -qmax 31 -b_qfactor 0.15 -b_qoffset 0.1 -i_qfactor 0.15 -i_qoffset 0.1 -me_method 'full' -me_quality 6 -me_range 1023 -mbd 'rd' -mpeg_quant 0 -v 0 -stats output.file
```

Its been awhile since I've looked at this, since I just gave up.
But I think the issue was that FFmpeg did not support all of the modes per setting that mencoder did. The -me* or -mbd vs vhq and bvhq. I don't remember where the difference was. But since the Xvid code is basicaly the same for both FFmpeg and Mencoder, I should be able to output near the same file size and quality.

Was the needed setting just not included in FFmpeg? Or am I missing something?

Comment: To complicate matters libxvid has several private options you can experiment with: `ffmpeg -h encoder=libxvid`. You can also compare the native FFmpeg MPEG-4 Part 2 video encoder `mpeg4`. IIRC, there was an article on the now defunct [Diary Of An x264 Developer](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/) blog that showed examples of high quality encoding with libxvid (or was it mpeg4 or maybe I'm not remembering anything correctly). Perhaps you can find it on archive.org.